# Getting Google Actions / Schemas into Google Now

Tags: gmail, action, schema.org, google-schemas, google-now

I have been sending test emails with schema.org markup included. They work fine in Gmail, displaying the Action buttons correctly. However they never come through to Google Now.

I've have tried package tracking, events, flights etc. Using my own code and the code examples provided on the Google Developers site. Google Now is set up to receive cards based on the Gmail account, but they never come through.

I can find many instances of people having exactly the same issue as me, but no one seems to have a solution. 
Can i just clarify this is NOT an issue with the SPF check or DKIM signatures in the header. The schema markup works perfectly in Gmail. This is just an issue with getting it to go from gmail through to Google Now.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Does this tutorial work for you: https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/google-now-cards

Comment: I had tried it with no luck. But I just realised I might need to play around with the time of the event to make sure it appears in google now. Thanks.